# Serialize JSON Before Inserting into Database

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a code where I am getting nested structures from coldfusion page.

I need to serialize the data into JSON to insert into SQL, I can do it from coldfusion, but its a very back and forth. Can I just pass struct to the SQL insert and SQL can convert into that a JSON and insert it?

Sounds like a silly question, but I am trying to minify the code wherever I can.

Here is my struct:

http://prntscr.com/mlye0r

```
<cfset myStruct = {
    "sd": {
        "sp": 100,
        "cn": 100,
        "id": 100
    }
}>
<cfdump var="#myStruct#">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your question, but if you are using javacript you can use `JSON.stringify({here your json})`, in order to serialize into a string. If your are using for you back, server languages like c#, you have some libraries like [newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). It´s really simple to use them....

If your problem is that your json file is huge, and the request to the server would take too long you can compress you json file into [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) But in any case, if this is your problem I recommend you to have a look first to your arquitecture in your background in order to send smaller request to the server.

Have a look to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) then. Since Sql server 2016 was uploaded, this feature you are looking for is possible.

Comment: that i know, but looking at sql docs where i want to avoid converting to serializejson before inserting in sql, just want to send that struct to sq and while inserting use sql functions to do it

Answer (score 0):

JSON support was introduced not before v2016. So the following code will need a SQL-Server-2016+:

You might introduce a stored procedure accepting a parameter of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and call this by passing over the struct *as is*. This is simulating the code within the SP:

```
DECLARE @YourStruct NVARCHAR(1000)=
N'<cfset myStruct = {
    "sd": {
        "sp": 100,
        "cn": 100,
        "id": 100
    }
}>
<cfdump var="#myStruct#">';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@YourStruct,N'<cfdump var="#myStruct#">',N''),CHARINDEX(N'{',@YourStruct),LEN(@YourStruct)),N'}>',N'}')),N'$.sd')
WITH(sp INT,cn INT, id INT);
```

You can read this as

- replace the `<cfdump var="#myStruct#">` with nothing
- start to read the string with the first opening `{`
- Replace the `}>` with a single `}`
- Use `JSON_QUERY()` to interpret this string as a JSON (and avoid escaped quotes)
- Use `OPENJSON()` to dive into the JSON and read its values
- Use a `WITH`-clause to get hands on the internal variables typed and directly

### Some thoughts about HTML - XHTML - XML...

Regretfully the struct looks like XML but is not valid XML (due to the invalid XML-attribute `myStruct`). It was much easier to retrieve this JSON from XHTML, but in this case you'd have to hand in your struct as

**Hint** doubled the single quotes for T-SQL-syntax...

```
DECLARE @YourStruct NVARCHAR(1000)=
N'<cfset myStruct = ''{
    "sd": {
        "sp": 100,
        "cn": 100,
        "id": 100
    }
}''/>
<cfdump var="#myStruct#"/>';
```

This was written as XML

```
SELECT CAST(@yourstruct as xml)

<cfset myStruct="{   &quot;sd&quot;: {    &quot;sp&quot;: 100,    &quot;cn&quot;: 100,    &quot;id&quot;: 100   }  }" />
<cfdump var="#myStruct#" />
```

This could be retrieved by native XML method `.value()`

```
SELECT CAST(@yourstruct as xml).value('(/cfset/@myStruct)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```